# Prime number test for numbers 1 - 1000

Tags: python, function, for-loop

As a homework I have to write a prime number test, that gives back a "true" or "false" statement. The tricky thing is, I have to write a csv.-file that includes the "true" and "false" statements for the numbers 1 to 1000.
I used this code for the prime number test

```
def Primzahl(n):
if n < 2:
    return False
if n == 2: 
    return True    
if not n & 1: 
    return False
for x in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2):
    if n % x == 0:
        return False
return True
```

and

```
for i in range (1,1001):
    Primzahl (i)
    print (i)
```

My for-loop only gives out the numbers 1,1000 but not the true or false statements. Do I have to include if and else in my for loop? Can anyone help?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. This code would cause a SyntaxError.

Comment: The primzahl function has a return value. You can use that. `if primzahl(i): print(i, 'is prime'); else: print(i, 'is not prime')`

Comment: Sorry I had some issues with the copy and pasting of my code. Just updated it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `print(i)`. That will write `i`, which is the number from your `range` call. You will also need to print the value returned by your function, e.g. `print(Primzahl(i))`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day and kinda just made more clear to me, how python works!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're only printing i, and not the return value from your method. You aren't doing anything with the return value from your method. You should assign the result to a variable and print the variable also. (You could also just call the method from within the print statement.)

```
for i in range (1,1001):
isPrime = Primzahl(i)
print (i + ": " + isPrime)
```